# image[:, :, 0:2]/255 and the shape change

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I once saw the following line of code

```
 image = image[:, :, 0:2]/255
```

Before running this line of code, image is of shape `[489,1489,3]`. But after running this line of code, the image is of shape `[489,1489,2]`. I think the divide operation, i.e., `image[:, :, 0:2]/255` should not change the shape. But it does change, which confused me.

Comment: Because you are reassigning?

Comment: If you remove the divide operation, the shape still changes, so clearly your problem is not the divide. Did you mean `0:3`?

Comment: It is slicing 101. `[..., 0:2]` picks two slices `[0, 2)`, the 2 is not included, thus, picking only the first two channels. Have a thorough look to numpy's  (python's) slicing mechanism or you will face more problems like this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the slicing that's changing the shape not the division:

```
In [11]: a = np.random.rand(9, 9, 9)

In [12]: a[0:2, :, :].shape
Out[12]: (2, 9, 9)

In [13]: a[:, 0:2, :].shape
Out[13]: (9, 2, 9)

In [14]: a[:, :, 0:2].shape
Out[14]: (9, 9, 2)

In [15]: (a[:, :, 0:2] / 255).shape
Out[15]: (9, 9, 2)
```

See the [numpy indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).

Answer (score 0):

ok , they divided with 255 because ,

Pixel values are often unsigned integers in the range between 0 and 255. Although these pixel values can be presented directly to neural network models in their raw format, this can result in challenges during modeling, such as in the slower than expected training of the model.

Instead, there can be great benefit in preparing the image pixel values prior to modeling, such as simply scaling pixel values to the range 0-1 to centering and even standardizing the values

i think now you will know